# Import errors in python project (pipenv, pytest)

Tags: python, pytest, pipenv

I have the following project structure

```
- src
  - main.py
  - foo
    - ...
- test
  - test_foo
    - ...
- Pipfile
- setup.cfg
```

If I run `pipenv run pytest test` I get import errors, because the *test* folder is outside the *src* folder and thus I cannot import the files correctly.

Is there a way to mark the *src* folder as my "source"-folder?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution, but I do not know if there is a better one.

I've added a `setup.py` file, where I defined, that my *src* folder should be my "source"-folder.

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name="data_generation",
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    packages=find_packages(where='src'),
)
```

To install everything I've run `pipenv install -e . --dev`. This is only needed for the first time, afterwards the `Pipfile` gets updated, and we can run `pipenv install --dev`.

Now we can run `pipenv run pytest test` and do not get any import errors anymore.

Comment: This is clearly the only solution when using the `src` layout (you are testing against the installed code and not against your source code repository).

Comment: Thanks @hoefling. I'm new to python, are there better layouts than the `src`-layout or is it fine to use the `src`-layout?

Comment: It's a matter of choice. I always prefer the `src` layout because it makes testing installed packages easy, but if you're not planning to release a library or an application to the world, it may also be an overkill.